# Find $c$ if density function for some random variable $X$ is given as $f(x)=cg(x)$ and find distribution function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So, the density function is given as $f(x)=c(1-x^2), \; -1 \le x \le 1$ and $0$ otherwise. But I couldn't find a constant $c$, because $c\int^1_{-1}(1-x^2)dx \neq 1 \; \forall c \in R$. Maybe there's some exceptions were integral of density function doesn't need to equal 1? And how do I find $F(x)$ in this case?

Comment: I think you should check your working on $\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)dx$ as it is not zero. Thus you can find such a $c$.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want is:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 c(1-x^2) \, dx = 1 $$
This means that:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2) \, dx = \frac{1}{c} $$
$$ \int_{-1}^1 1 - x^2 \, dx = x - \frac{x^3}{3}\Big|_{-1}^{1}  = \frac{4}{3} $$
$$ c = \frac{3}{4} $$